# Bug report: comments.list fails on apps script files

Tags: google-drive-api

drive.comments.list returns file not found on apps script files.

Drive.files.get is successful for this file:

Files.get succeeds.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1mRd1rNjih8iiMAATstEyr3A6KBpkRZaiTpFa5gLM1G70Yd9F9sXi5d2R?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

200 OK
```

Comments.list fails.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1mRd1rNjih8iiMAATstEyr3A6KBpkRZaiTpFa5gLM1G70Yd9F9sXi5d2R/comments?key={YOUR_API_KEY}



404 Not Found

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: 1mRd1rNjih8iiMAATstEyr3A6KBpkRZaiTpFa5gLM1G70Yd9F9sXi5d2R"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: 1mRd1rNjih8iiMAATstEyr3A6KBpkRZaiTpFa5gLM1G70Yd9F9sXi5d2R"
 }
}
```

Comment: It's a bug, on our backlog for fixes, thanks!

Comment: I was able to retrieve files for the past 3 hours, and I'm getting this error right now! :( So frustrating...